# consistent matched pairs in R

Tags: r, for-loop, matching

So using the `Matching` Package [(Link to package here)](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matching/Matching.pdf)

We can work through a modified `GenMatch` example.

```
library(Matching)
data(lalonde)

#introduce an id vaiable
lalonde$ID <- 1:length(lalonde$age)

X = cbind(lalonde$age, lalonde$educ, lalonde$black, lalonde$hisp, 
          lalonde$married, lalonde$nodegr, lalonde$u74, lalonde$u75, 
          lalonde$re75, lalonde$re74)

BalanceMat <- cbind(lalonde$age, lalonde$educ, lalonde$black, 
                    lalonde$hisp, lalonde$married, lalonde$nodegr, 
                    lalonde$u74, lalonde$u75, lalonde$re75, lalonde$re74, 
                    I(lalonde$re74*lalonde$re75))

genout <- GenMatch(Tr=lalonde$treat, X=X, BalanceMatrix=BalanceMat, estimand="ATE", 
                   pop.size=16, max.generations=10, wait.generations=1)

mout <- Match(Y=NULL, Tr=lalonde$treat, X=X,
              Weight.matrix=genout,
              replace=TRUE, ties=FALSE)
```

```
# here we set ties FALSE so we only have 1-1 Matching
summary(mout)

#now lets create our "Matched dataset"
treated <- lalonde[mout$index.treated,]
# and introduce an indetity variable for each pair
treated$Pair_ID <- treated$ID

non.treated <- lalonde[mout$index.control,]
non.treated$Pair_ID <- treated$ID

matched.data <- rbind(treated, non.treated)
matched.data <- matched.data[order(matched.data$Pair_ID),]

#this outputs which of the non-treated ID was paired with the first person
matched.data$ID[matched.data$Pair_ID==1 & matched.data$treat==0]
```

We see that for the data, the **ID=1 is matched with ID=193**

Now lets introduce some randomisation into the order of the data and see if we get the same pairs

```
n <- 500
P1 <- rep(NA, n)
P2 <- rep(NA, n)
P3 <- rep(NA, n)
P4 <- rep(NA, n)
P5 <- rep(NA, n)
P6 <- rep(NA, n)
P7 <- rep(NA, n)

for (i in 1:n) {
  lalonde <- lalonde[sample(1:nrow(lalonde)), ] # randomise order
  genout <- GenMatch(Tr=lalonde$treat, X=X, BalanceMatrix=BalanceMat, estimand="ATE", 
                     pop.size=16, max.generations=10, wait.generations=1)
  mout <- Match(Y=NULL, Tr=lalonde$treat, X=X,
                Weight.matrix=genout,
                replace=TRUE, ties=FALSE)
  summary(mout)
  treated <- lalonde[mout$index.treated,]
  treated$Pair_ID <- treated$ID
  non.treated <- lalonde[mout$index.control,]
  non.treated$Pair_ID <- treated$ID
  matched.data <- rbind(treated, non.treated)
  matched.data <- matched.data[order(matched.data$Pair_ID),]
  P1[i] <- matched.data$ID[matched.data$Pair_ID==1 & matched.data$treat==0]
  P2[i] <- matched.data$ID[matched.data$Pair_ID==2 & matched.data$treat==0]
  P3[i] <- matched.data$ID[matched.data$Pair_ID==3 & matched.data$treat==0]
  P4[i] <- matched.data$ID[matched.data$Pair_ID==4 & matched.data$treat==0]
  P5[i] <- matched.data$ID[matched.data$Pair_ID==5 & matched.data$treat==0]
  P6[i] <- matched.data$ID[matched.data$Pair_ID==6 & matched.data$treat==0]
  P7[i] <- matched.data$ID[matched.data$Pair_ID==7 & matched.data$treat==0]
}
```

So the `loop` will match the pairs 500 times and `P1` will save the `treat==0` case each time.

We then look at the which `P1` appears the most, by:

```
plot(1:n, P1, main="P1")
```

OR

```
summary(as.factor(P1))
```

We see that no one `treat==0` case is commonly paired.
I would expect there to be a case (possibly =193??) that is commonly paired that does not depend on the order of the data. Therefore I think my loop is wrong. Can anybody point out where? Or when they run a loop, they find, independent of the order of the data, that similar cases are paired??

Comment: I am not sure if the `GenMatch` needs to be called into the loop, if removed, simulation time significantly reduces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you randomise the order of `lalonde`, but your input to `GenMatch` and `Match` are `X` and `BalanceMat` which still have the original order. When you then build your `matched.data` at the end, you are subsetting using indices which don't tie into `lalonde` any more. Try again but including the assignment of `X` and `BalanceMat` in your loop.

i.e.

```
X = cbind(lalonde$age, lalonde$educ, lalonde$black, lalonde$hisp, 
          lalonde$married, lalonde$nodegr, lalonde$u74, lalonde$u75, 
          lalonde$re75, lalonde$re74)

BalanceMat <- cbind(lalonde$age, lalonde$educ, lalonde$black, 
                    lalonde$hisp, lalonde$married, lalonde$nodegr, 
                    lalonde$u74, lalonde$u75, lalonde$re75, lalonde$re74, 
                    I(lalonde$re74*lalonde$re75))
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for the help mate!!